# Averge calculation codeigniter query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Iam trying to find average of rate,but below codeignier query results error "Unknown column 'prate' in 'field list'"

```
 $this->db->select('AVG(prate)as avgprate');
        $this->db->from('stock','(select sum((pdetails.quantity*pdetails.rate)/pdetails.quantity) AS prate FROM `stock` INNER JOIN `pdetails` ON `pdetails`.`stock_id` = `stock`.`stock_id`)');

        $result = $this->db->get();
        $res = $result->row();
```

How can i solve this

Comment: double check your `stock` table has a column name `prate`

Comment: No ,i define this field in where condition `$this->db->where('stock.stock_id in','(select sum((pdetails.quantity*pdetails.rate)/pdetails.quantity) AS prate ` -@RejoanulAlam

Comment: Your first course of action is determining if the generated SQL is the same as the intended ( and hopefully fully tested ) SQL... So after your get, put in either an echo or var_dump of $this->db->last_query() and observe the generated SQL.

Comment: I got the query like this `SELECT AVG(prate)as samout FROM `stock`WHERE stock.stock_id in(select sum((pdetails.quantity*pdetails.rate)/pdetails.quantity) AS prate FROM `stock` INNER JOIN `pdetails` ON `pdetails`.`stock_id` = `stock`.`stock_id`)` -@TimBrownlaw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->db->select('AVG(t.prate)as avgprate');
        $this->db->from('stock ,(select sum((pdetails.quantity*pdetails.rate)/pdetails.quantity) AS prate FROM `stock` INNER JOIN `pdetails` ON `pdetails`.`stock_id` = `stock`.`stock_id`)t');

        $result = $this->db->get();
        $res = $result->row();
```